# TideSDK: Wix.msi installer for 32-bit Win7 OS

Tags: tidesdk

I'm trying to package an app using tideSDK and I've been searching out for wix.msi installer that would work with a 32-bit OS, in my search I've able to download the one that works for 64-bit OS , but my Win7 OS is 32-bit.

Comment: Can you compile your own? Where did you get the 64-bit one, is there not a 32-bit one there?

Comment: i got one from github but didnt find any one for 32-bit OS there